# How do I choose a regression model after using best subsets regression?

Tags: r, math, statistics, linear-regression

I'm using the leaps package in R for an assignment. I was given an outcome variable and 20 independent variables and told to find the model with which the data points were generated. I've narrowed it down to two models which differ only by one second-order interaction. My level of significance is 0.001 and my t-value is 3.295 on 1999 df. When I check models that include this second-order interaction, its t-value is very close to but just above 3.295, and its p-value is just about 0.000991.

Is there a way to be sure I'm not committing a Type I error by including this term? I was told to plug the variables into a regression without their interaction terms, and if they remain significant, then they are probably in the model. However, my professor has also explained to us that the simplest explanation is often the correct one (Occam's Razor).

I'm sorry if this is too vague, but I'm very hesitant to post too much information about the project online.

Comment: It is hard to point you in the right direction without proper context. Where is your data? Are you looking for a model that better explains the variation in data or that would make good predictions? Adjusted-R-square or AIC would be a better metric for comparison rather than p-value or t statistic. I strongly encourage you to go to office hours and study the class material. Learn it once and for good.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. After looking at it all night I think I finally got it. The second model has a slightly higher adjusted r-squared (about .77 compared to .75), but I wasn't sure if that meant a significant difference. Most of the tests I performed on that model pointed me to rejecting the null (in terms of that specific interaction), but I was just worried about Type I errors.

Answer (score 0):

In model selection, as you pointed out, you generally want to take more parsimonious models so that they have fewer assumptions. Adjusted R squared works; more popular methods though are the Akaike's Information Criterion and Bayesian Information Criterion. Normally BIC is more conservative than AIC. When people use AIC or BIC they generally want a *lower* score. There is no such thing as significance because it's an entirely relative measure.

When you talk about significant difference i think you are talking about analysis of deviance. Likelihoods are distributed on a chi squared distribution, so you *can* test the difference between two models using a log likelihood ratio test, or an ANOVA if the two models are nested within each other, which sounds like what you are describing where the models only differ by adding a parameter. Whether an individual contrast of a parameter is signifcant or not doesn't necessarily make your model a better fit, so what you want to do is test the entire model against a model that is almost the same as it.

The code is simply `anova(reducedmodel, fullmodel)`
alternatively, the log likelihood ratio test can be done using the `lmtest` package `lrtest(fullmodel,reducedmodel)`